# Jquery animate method not recognising property after concat

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have created an `animate()` method that takes the push direction and timing of the animation from the `data-` attributes of the clicked elements:

HTML

```
<div class="caja" data-empuje="top" data-tiempo="500">Caja 1</div>
<div class="caja" data-empuje="left" data-tiempo="100">Caja 2</div>
<div class="caja" data-empuje="right" data-tiempo="400">Caja 3</div>
<div class="caja" data-empuje="bottom" data-tiempo="900">Caja 4</div>
```

JS

```
$('.caja').on('click', function(){

            var empuje = $(this).data('empuje');
            var tiempo = $(this).data('tiempo');

            var stringEmpuje = "margin-" + empuje;      //alerts correctly (for example, 'margin-top')

            $(this).animate({
                stringEmpuje: '-=40px',
                opacity: 0
            }, tiempo);
        });
```

Timing works correctly, but direction is not applying even when the `stringEmpuje` var alerts final string correctly, and should be recognised by jQuery as a CSS property, but it does not apply.

[LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nho0mk6g/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass the value of `stringEmpuje` as a key to to the `animate` method. If so, try this:

```
$('.caja').on('click', function(){

    var empuje = $(this).data('empuje');
    var tiempo = $(this).data('tiempo');

    var stringEmpuje = "margin-" + empuje;
    var animOptions = {
        opacity: 0
    };
    animOptions[stringEmpuje] = '-=40px';

    $(this).animate(animOptions, tiempo);
});
```

With ES2015 you can simply do:

```
$('.caja').on('click', function(){

    var empuje = $(this).data('empuje');
    var tiempo = $(this).data('tiempo');

    var stringEmpuje = "margin-" + empuje;

    $(this).animate({
        [stringEmpuje]: '-=40px',
        opacity: 0
    }, tiempo);
});
```